# No overload matches this call error: React Native Navigation

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm pretty new to React Native and React Native Navigation. I'm getting an error stating:

```
    "message": "No overload matches this call.\n  Overload 1 of 2, '(...args: never): void', gave the following error.\n    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.\n  Overload 2 of 2, '(options: never): void', gave the following error.\n    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.",
```

in regards to `'Signup'`. Previously, I wasn't getting this issue, and I can't seem to figure out why this is occurring. All of the examples that I've found don't pertain to problems with navigation. I tried adding `<RootStackParamList>` to `navigation.navigate<RootStackParamList>('Conversation')`, but that just caused another error, and adding it to `useNavigation` did nothing. I would really appreciate any help or advice on why I might be getting this issue. Thank you!

HomeScreen.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { 
  Text, 
  TextInput, 
  Pressable, 
  ActivityIndicator, 
} from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Text, View } from '../components/Themed';*/
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';
import { RootStackParamList} from '../navigation/types';

export default function HomeScreen() {
  
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Pressable 
        onPress={() => {console.warn('navigate'); navigation.navigate('Signup')}} 
      >
        <Text 
            New here? Sign up
        </Text>
      </Pressable>   
    </View>
  );
}
);
```

types.tsx

```
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native';

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Conversation: undefined;
  Login: undefined;
  Signup: undefined;
  NotFound: undefined;
  Splash: undefined;
};

export type MessageNavProps<T extends keyof RootStackParamList> = {
  navigation: StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, T>;
  route: RouteProp<RootStackParamList, T>;
};
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error you're seeing is at the Typescript level, so it won't prevent you from using the navigator. It tells you that the navigator isn't typed, so it's not expecting to navigate anywhere.

You can change the useNavigation call to look like this:

`const { navigate } = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>();`

and react-navigation will get the route names from your param list.

Answer (score 21):

When using `native-stack`, usage will look like this:

```
import {ParamListBase, useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {NativeStackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Component = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<ParamListBase>>();
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to go with the simpler and a bit hacker way.. just do this:

```js
navigation.navigate("YourRouteName" as never);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when you use a function incorrectly or miss input parameters. You need to check the syntax and make sure that all input parameters are passed in the correct data type.

If the error occurs during navigation, check if you have registered all screens and routes correctly. If there are any issues, refer to the documentation of the routing library or review your source code to identify the specific error.

If you are unable to resolve the issue on your own, seek help from the programming community.

```
import {useNavigation, ParamListBase} from '@react-navigation/native';

import {NativeStackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const navigation = useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<ParamListBase>>();
```

Comment: Did you use chatgpt for this?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34204657)