# The navigation of useNavigation() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to use the navigation that comes from the @react-navigation/native library but it keeps showing this error:

```
No overhead matches this call.
   Overloading 1 of 2, '(...args: never): void', generated the following error.
     Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
   The 2 of 2 overload, '(options: never): void', generated the following error.
     Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2769)
```

I've already solved the typing problem, now all that's missing is the navigation that doesn't change to the other component

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import LogoSvg from '../../assets/logo_background_gray.svg';
import DoneSvg from '../../assets/done.svg';

import { Container, Content, Footer, Mensage, Title } from './styles';
import { ConfirmButton } from '../../components/ConfirmButton';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export function SchedulingComplete() {
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  function handleConfirm() {
    navigation.navigate('Home');
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle="light-content"
        translucent
        backgroundColor="transparent"
      />
      <LogoSvg width={width} />

      <Content>
        <DoneSvg width={80} height={80} />
        <Title>Carro Alugado</Title>

        <Mensage>
          Agora é só voce ir até{'\n'}a concessionária{'\n'}começar a dirigir
        </Mensage>
      </Content>

      <Footer>
        <ConfirmButton title="OK" onPress={handleConfirm} />
      </Footer>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

And in de router is

```
import React from 'react';

import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { Home } from '../screens/Home';
import { Scheduling } from '../screens/Scheduling';
import { SchedulingComplete } from '../screens/SchedulingComplete';
import { SchedulingDetails } from '../screens/SchedulingDetails';
import { CarDetails } from '../screens/CarDetails';

const { Navigator, Screen } = createNativeStackNavigator();

export function StackRoutes() {
  return (
    <Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} initialRouteName="Home">
      <Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Screen name="CarDetails" component={CarDetails} />
      <Screen name="Scheduling" component={Scheduling} />
      <Screen name="SchedulingDetails" component={SchedulingDetails} />
      <Screen name="SchedulingComplete" component={SchedulingComplete} />
    </Navigator>
  );
}
```

github of this project [is here](https://github.com/weslley281/rentx_mobile.git)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No overload matches this call error: React Native Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73861337/no-overload-matches-this-call-error-react-native-navigation)

Comment: _"I've already solved the typing problem"_... then why even mention it? What happens when you try to navigate now? Do you get any different errors reported?